# ColorFunction for even rows in an array

Tags: plotting, color

I want to show even rows in an array in gray, and non-even rows in black/white.

```
ArrayPlot[Array[GCD, {20, 20}], 
 ColorFunction -> (If[# == 1, Black, White] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

I don't know how to specify this from `ColorFunction`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a special value to rows that are even and then use `ColorRules` or `ColorFunction`. Here I demonstrate `ColorRules`:

```
ArrayPlot[
 Array[If[EvenQ[#], 0, GCD[#, #2]] &, {20, 20}],
 ColorRules -> {0 -> Gray, 1 -> Black, _ -> White}
 ]
```